# Want to install Facebook/Gmail chat to my web application

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook, gmail

I am looking to install Facebook chat and/or Google chat to my web application. Does anybody have a useful tool for this?

Comment: They both use Jabber, so you can use any Jabber client/library.  However, this will require server support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a real time chat in your app with facebook : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/live-stream

For Google Talk which uses the XMPP protocol, try the [strophejs library](https://github.com/metajack/strophejs). You can take a look at the Google talk api docs : http://code.google.com/apis/talk/

Comment: I think the Live Stream plugin is for "sharing" (basically, posting stuff to news feeds), not Facebook chat.  Also, strophejs [requires](http://metajack.wordpress.com/2008/06/30/strophe-preview-xmpp-in-javascript/#comment-257) a BOSH service on the server.